# How can I display data for the current view from a different table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables:

```
Chords -     |id|chord|name|rating|artist_id|
Artists -    |id|artist|
```

An `Artist` has many `Chord`s, and thus a `Chord` belongs to an `Artist`.

And in the index page for "chords" I want to display chord, name, and rating from Chords table and the artist from the artists table

This is the code for the `Chord`'s index.html.erb:

```
<table border="1">
  <% @chords.each do |chord| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= chord.artist.artist %></td>
       <td><%= link_to chord.name, chord %></td>
       <td><%= chord.rating %></td>
       <td><%= chord.created_at %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The error message is:

> undefined method `artist' for nil:NilClass

Actually, at first it worked, but when I started to create the "new.html.erb" page and the create and new actions, it stopped working, that's why this is so confusing to me!

Comment: Why `<%=chord.artist.artist%>` rather than `<%=chord.artist%>`?  Though the first `artist` appears to be nil in this case.

Comment: @Michael it seems to be the only Artist attribute, maybe it's the name.

Comment: Please add your Models to the question

Answer (score 0):

Since `chort.artist` can be null, you should change `chord.artist.artist` to `chord.artist.try(:artist)` which is shorthand for

```
if chord.artist.nil?
  nil
else
  chord.artist.artist
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use
`<td><%= chord.artist.artist unless chord.artist.artist.nil? %></td>`

Comment: This will result in the same error `undefined method 'artist' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score -1):

In the view is no the right place to do it but what you need to do is find the artist with the ID given in the CHORDS like this

```
   @currentArtist = Artist.find(:all, :conditions => {:protectora => Chord.artist_id})
```

Then when you find it by the ID given in the CHORD and save it in to a variable, you can access it like any other variable so:

```
   @currentArtist.artist
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: -1 This is really a bad practice! And there is no need for this since ActiveRecord makes the join for you.

Comment: Then how do you access an Artist by the ID?

Comment: It's supposed to be assessable at chord.artist, but there is some problem in this case, and that's why it dosent work. You should read about ActiveRecord before answering this question. And if you are a Rails developer, you sure are doing it the wrong way